# jquery .on() toggle div

Tags: jquery

i'm developing a blog with dynamic content loaded via ajax request and i'm trying
to hide/show the "post comment" form, of the article, with a button :

```
<div id="post">
...
  <ol id="update" class="timeline">
    <!-- comments here -->
  </ol>
  <button class="mybutton Bhome">Commenta</button><!-- hide/show button -->
  <div class="mycomment"><!-- div to hide/show -->
    <form action="#" method="post">
      Nome:
      <input type="text" size="12" id="name" /><br />
      Email:
      <input type="text" size="12" id="email" /><br />
      <textarea rows="10" cols="50" class="mytext" id="commentArea"></textarea><br />
      <input type="submit" class="Bhome" value=" Post " />
    </form>
  </div><!-- mycomment --> 
</div><!-- post -->
```

This jquery code works well but has effect on All the posts...

```
$("div").on("click", ".mybutton", function(e){ 
  $(".mycomment").slideToggle("slow");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I want that only the clicked hide/show button has effect on the related article but f i have more than one article on my page the button with `.mybutton` class hides or shows all the comment form of all the articles.

Comment: What's your wrapper for each article? I would've guessed <div id="post">, but that can't be right because you couldn't have more than one of those per page.

Comment: my blog is so experimental .. :) i use mysqli to get all the articles and build a string for html...  yes.. i think i will put only one post per page...

Comment: So, in the end if you only put one post per page, you wouldn't need this question answered, right? Or is there something else going on here I'm missing?

Comment: ..yes .. the on() function is a little more difficult to use than live() with which i tried in the past. I wanted to know why i must bind the click event to all the document's divs.. and not to a specific one. Do you think that the most common way to build a blog is to put one post per page.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will always have a `.mybutton` button followed by the `.mycomment` div that you want to hide, all you need to do is find the next sibling `.mycomment` to the button being pushed like this:

```
$("div").on("click", ".mybutton", function(e){ 
    $(this).next(".mycomment").slideToggle("slow");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note the use of `next()` method to find the next `.mycomment` element that is a sibling to the clicked `.mybutton`.